# VBA - Userform new instance

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a main userform where I do all my calculations and I want to display them on my image forms. I tried to use:

```
Dim newInstance As New diagramGUI
newInstance.Show vbModeless
```

but then I cant access the data from the main userform. Is there any workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a public variable in the `diagramGUI` userform to point the the instance of MainUserForm.

Add this line to the `diagramGUI` code module

> ```
>  Public Controller as MainUserForm
> ```

Then set the reference from the `MainUserForm` after you instantiate then new `diagramGUI`

> ```
>  Dim newInstance As New diagramGUI
>  Set newInstance.Controller = Me
>  newInstance.Show vbModeless
> ```